# What's the benefit of building and injecting a script tag for 3rd party APIs?

Tags: javascript

[The Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/) and the [Google+ OAuth signin](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button), as well as many others, build out a script tag and inject that tag into the head. What is the benefit to doing this over just adding the script tag directly?

Comment: not all browsers support the async attribute?

Comment: it might also help stop dumb robots from backtracking the script src attrib...

Comment: Closed because it's opinion-based? What exactly is opinion-based about the benefits of a technique that many of the largest websites on the planet employ? I had no idea that it was primarily because it loads asynchronously... I thought this would be a good site to ask these kinds of questions... I guess I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a script tag this way makes it asynchronous. From the linked Google+ OAuth signin

> The above example follows the best practice of using [asynchronous loading of the JavaScript file](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#loading_the_javascript_api_asynchronously)  for improved performance.

Comment: To clarify, this is makes it asynchronous for very old browsers. Typically, you can use less hackish means to make the script loading asynchronous.

Comment: this is makes it asynchronous for all browsers, including old ones. Other than adding an async=true, what would you suggest?

Comment: i would suggest not caring and letting old browser users wait the extra 1/4th of a second.

Comment: Yes, what @dandavis said. I wasn't saying it's *only* for old browers, but that you don't need to do DOM manipulation to make it asynchronous for 99% of the browers people use (I think).

Comment: IE < 10, Opera < 15, and android 2.* are certainly more than 1% of the internet, and for some unfortunate souls, it is a huge chunk of their website traffic.